# Prob. 20, Chap. 2, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: Does $E$ necessarily have to have finite outer measure?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure, measurable-sets

Here is Prob. 20, Chap. 2, in the book *Real Analysis* by H. L. Royden and P. M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> Let $E$ have finite outer measure. Show that $E$ is measurable if and only if for each open bounded interval $(a, b)$,
> $$
> b-a = m^* \big( (a, b) \cap E \big) + m^* \big( (a, b) \setminus E \big). \tag{1} 
> $$

By definition of measurability, $E$ is measurable if (and only if), for any set $A$, we have the equality
$$
m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^* \left( A \cap E^c \right),
$$
where $E^c = \mathbb{R} \setminus E$, that is,
$$
m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^* ( A \setminus E).
$$

And, we also have $$ m^* \big( (a, b) \big) = b-a. $$

In the light of the observations in the preceding two paragraphs, is it necessary here for set $E$ to have *finite* outer measure?

More specifically, can we not state the following?

> The set $E$---whether of finite outer measure or not---is measurable if and only if for any bounded open interval $(a, b)$, the identity (1) holds.

Comment: there's probably some counterexample to $E$ having non-finite outer measure, satisfying the condition and being non-measurable.  Remember, the condition for measurability is that the equality holds for every subset.

Comment: @NickCastillo can you be more explicit in what you stated in your previsou comment? Can you please write out a full-scale answer, elaborating on each and every aspect of this problem?